# Is it possible to get inactive azure ad users?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

How can i get inactive azure ad users more than 90 days?

```
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-90)
get-azureaduser -All $true -Filter {(LastLogonDate -lt $date) -and (accountEnabled eq true)}
```

Comment: Here's a [ps1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Get-AzureADStaleUsers/1.0/Content/Get-AzureADStaleUsers.ps1) that does just that. You also are missing the `-` before your operator `-eq`, and you should really be comparing to `$true` rather.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DO you have access to graph? This will get you the results you want

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2022-05-01T00:00:00Z&$filter=accountEnabled eq true&$select=displayName,signInActivity
```

Just make sure your account has the following permissions
AuditLog.Read.All
Directory.Read.All

All you'd need to adjust is the date that you want to filter signInActivity by.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts